# Undetermined Coefficients Method - I'm getting the wrong answer and don't know why

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve $$y''' - 3y'' +3y' - y = x-4e^x$$ I use $y_p$ in the form $Ax+B+Ce^x$. I almost get the right answer, but just one of my terms is incorrect, and one of my signs is incorrect. 
I am getting $$y = c_1e^x + c_2xe^x + c_3x^2e^x - 2e^x - x + 3$$ but the answer is $$y = c_1e^x + c_2xe^x + c_3x^2e^x - 2/3x^3e^x - x - 3$$
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The associated homogeneous auxiliary equation is
$$m^3-3m^2+3m-1=0$$
$$(m-1)^3=0$$
$$m=1$$
Hence the complementary function is
$$y_c=(A+Bx+Cx^2)e^x$$
So the particular solution is of the form
$$y_p=Dx+E+Fx^3e^x$$

Comment: How did you get Fx^3e^x? @peter foreman ?

Comment: In general, if $f(x)$ is in the original equation and the complementary function then we can try $xf(x), x^2f(x)$ etc. until we have a unique function that is not in the complementary function or the original equation.

Comment: oh I understand now! Thank you!